# How to create button X inside fragment A that will replace fragment A to fragment B

Tags: android, button, replace, switch-statement, fragment

I have fragment A and button X inside it. When I click on button X, the fragment A will be replaced by fragment B? How should I do that? Thank a lot.

Comment: This has nothing to do with english.  _What programming language?_

Comment: I am so sorry. I already edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void changeFragment(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    xyzFragment fragment = new xyzFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.details_fragment, fragment );
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
}
```

1. xyzFragmetn :  Another Fragment that contain button.
2. call changeFragment() method to change the fragment

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is your method changeFragment in fragment A or FragmentAcivity?

Comment: Sorry for my bad knowledge. I'm a newbie in andoid. I've just tried your method inside the Fragment A and it works. It call the Fragment B out but both of them appear on my Screen. Is there any way to show only the Fragment B ? Thanks